# How to reuse component

Tags: javascript, code-duplication

I have a component A which has component B and component C as children, because B and C need one same service so I defined it in A and transfer it to B and C as parameter. However, I need to use component B out of component A now. Do I need to rewrite the service and pass it to B? This will introduce code-duplication so I think it is not a good practice, but this is the only way I know. Any better practice?

Comment: What exactly does this service do? Maybe you should define seperate file like eg. utils.js or services.js, which you could import in any component and use same service over and over again

Comment: How about pulling the service code or that functionality as a separate module like a helper.